# In WPF, long word doesn't wrap in the first line if there's some text before it

Tags: wpf, xaml, word-wrap, textblock

I'm having trouble with wrapping some text in a `TextBox` in WPF.
Let's say I have following text "Here is some VeryLongTextThatHasToBeWrapped and so on".

```
<TextBox Text="Here is some VeryLongTextThatHasToBeWrapped and so on" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="70" Height="150"/>
```

I'd expect that text would wrap in the first line as it doesn't fit in the `TextBox`. Like here:
[Expected wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEGKQ.png)

However wrapping happens on the next line, so I have unused space and the whole text does't fit in the TextBlock. Like here:
[Actual wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOIqe.png)

I tried to play with `Width` and `Height` , tried to set `TextWrapping` to `WrapWithOverflow` .
Also, I played aroud with `Run` elements with `InlineUIContainer` with no luck.

Still can't get the desired result.
Is there any way to "force" wrapping to break a word as soon a possible instead of giving it maximum possible space and then breaking it?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider string as array of chars and present it in an `ItemsControl`, where you set `ItemsPanel` to `WrapPanel`, of course it's then not editable.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="Here is some VeryLongTextThatHasToBeWrapped and so on" MaxWidth="70">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```